# Inflating view from within instance not working

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view, layout-inflater

I'm creating an adapter that should populate a GridView with images of cars, and a model name. I have created a grid item as an own XML-file, with the desired widgets (ImageView and TextView). However, I can't seem to inflate the view from within my `CarsGridViewItem` instance. It works if I inflate the view from the `getView`-method of my adapter however.

What happens if I inflate the view from within the `CarsGridViewItem` instance, is that I can't see the view that's supposed to be inflated.

Below is my `CarsGridViewItem` class

```
public class CarsGridViewItem extends RelativeLayout {

    private Car car;

    private ImageView carImg;
    private TextView nameTxt;

    public CarsGridViewItem(Car car, Context context) {
        super(context);

        this.car = car;

        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.fragment_cars_grid_item, this);
        findViews();
        setupViews();
    }

    private void findViews() {
        this.carImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.car_image);
        this.nameTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.car_name);
    }

    private void setupViews(){
        this.car.loadImageIntoView(this.carImg);
        this.nameTxt.setText(this.car.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean b, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3) {

    }
}
```

And the `getView`-method of my adapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    return new CarsGridViewItem(cars.get(position), mContext);

    /* The code below works!

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cars_grid_item, null);

    ImageView carImg = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.car_image);
    cars.get(position).loadImageIntoView(carImg);

    TextView nameTxt = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.car_name);
    nameTxt.setText(cars.get(position).getName());

    return view;*/
}
```

I'm doing something wrong here, but I can't seem to figure out what. All the examples I've found on the topic of inflating views does it like this!

Comment: You can debug and see how the view is being laid out. `Show layout bounds` or `Tools-> Android -> Layout Inspector`. It seems to me your view has 0 height.

Comment: Great tip with the Layout Inspector. This shows me that the `CarsGridViewItem` has a width and height, whereas the inflated RelativeLayout within doesn't have a width and height! What could be causing this?

Comment: Post also `CarsGridViewItem` class.

Comment: @azizbekian updated with the entire `CarsGridViewItem` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either remove `onMeasure()` and `onLayout()` methods from `CarsGridViewItem` or implement them correctly, because you do not override them correctly now.

You have overriden `onLayout()` and are doing nothing there, thus nothing is being laid out. Let the super class layout the view for you.

Comment: I don't even know why I had the onLayout-method overridden, think that my IDE added it for some reason... Works great, thank you very much!